# How to use variables used in *ngFor/*ngIf to fill the html element properties

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I try to use variable from ngIf to fill the name property of my html element but I can't

I've try to use x from `ngif="x.child"` but it seems that it doesn't work

```js
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of tabRes">
    <div *ngIf="x.child" style="display:block" name="x.nom" >
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
            <li *ngFor = "let y of x.child" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">{{y.nom}}</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

when I check in my browser element's name is `x.nom`. I want to use value of this one to field my property

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Please clear the logic first. Do you want to loop through *x.child* only if *x.child* is not blank? What does x look like?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here. Your  check is basicially say if x.child is true show the div. Is that your intention?

Comment: Sorry guys. Some ```x``` havn't property child, some other have it. I create the div only for those with this property. Style property is set to try to hide/show them after resolving the problem. what I want is to set div name property with ```"nom"``` property of ```x```. I Don't know if I'm enougth clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression `name="x.nom"` `x.nom` is a string. To be interpreted as a variable, the attribute should be placed inside square brackets, i.e. `[name]="x.nom"`.

That being said, a `div` does not have a `name` attribute. Use `id` instead.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. When I try your solution I got the next error : ```Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'div'```

Comment: @claudem, `div` does not have a property `name`. Did you mean `id` instead of `name`?

Comment: @claudem, what does it mean _to field a property_?